# How to handle initial nil value for reduce functions

Tags: swift, functional-programming, reduce

I would like to learn and use more functional programming in Swift. So, I've been trying various things in playground. I don't understand Reduce, though. The basic textbook examples work, but I can't get my head around this problem.

I have an array of strings called "toDoItems". I would like to get the longest string in this array. What is the best practice for handling the initial nil value in such cases? I think this probably happens often. I thought of writing a custom function and use it.

```
func optionalMax(maxSofar: Int?, newElement: Int) -> Int {
    if let definiteMaxSofar = maxSofar {
        return max(definiteMaxSofar, newElement)
    }
    return newElement
}   

// Just testing - nums is an array of Ints. Works.
var maxValueOfInts = nums.reduce(0) { optionalMax($0, $1) }   

// ERROR: cannot invoke 'reduce' with an argument list of type ‘(nil, (_,_)->_)'
var longestOfStrings = toDoItems.reduce(nil) { optionalMax(count($0), count($1)) }
```

Comment: Map and reduce both transform the collections they are passed, whereas what you are trying to do is find something in the collection. This is why you have an ugly edge case to code around. Consider using a different algorithm, such as the one @EricD suggests.

Comment: Don't understand. reduce() doesn't transform the original array. The way I'm trying to use it is very similar to how I use it to find a maximum among Ints (in the second to last line of code above.) It simply is a use on a different data type.

Comment: It doesn't transform the original array in place, indeed, but it does apply a transformation to the array's elements and returns the result of this transformation.

Comment: So, what is wrong in my example? You can't do this with reduce?

Comment: You can, I just thought it was a bad fit for reduce(), but after thinking about it, I think it's fine...I have an answer at the bottom!

Comment: Did you notice that your code doesn't fit you problem description? You said you want the _longest string_ **not** _the length of the longest string_ in your array.

Comment: Oops, you're right, I've updated my answer

Comment: Sorry, was an oversight in my description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might just be that Swift does not automatically infer the type of your initial value. Try making it clear by explicitly declaring it:

```
var longestOfStrings = toDoItems.reduce(nil as Int?) { optionalMax($0, count($1)) }
```

By the way notice that I do not count on `$0` (your accumulator) since it is not a `String` but an optional Int `Int?`

Generally to avoid confusion reading the code later, I explicitly label the accumulator as `a` and the element coming in from the serie as `x`:

```
var longestOfStrings = toDoItems.reduce(nil as Int?) { a, x in optionalMax(a, count(x)) }
```

This way should be clearer than `$0` and `$1` in code when the accumulator or the single element are used.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Initialise it with an empty string `""` rather than `nil`. Or you could even initialise it with the first element of the array, but an empty string seems better.

Comment: Yes, I agree, that would seem like the obvious choice. However, that doesn't work. I can't pass an empty string to my function. It expects an Int. I tried this but it also doesn't work either: 
var longestOfStrings = toDoItems.reduce(count(toDoItems.first!)) { optionalMax(count($0), count($1)) }

Answer (score 1):

Second go at this after writing some wrong code, this will return the longest string if you are happy with an empty string being returned for an empty array:

> toDoItems.reduce("") { count($0) > count($1) ? $0 : $1 }

Or if you want nil, use

> toDoItems.reduce(nil as String?) { count($0!) > count($1) ? $0 : $1 }

The problem is that the compiler cannot infer the types you are using for your seed and accumulator closure if you seed with nil, and you also need to get the optional type correct when using the optional string as $0.

Comment: Thanks for this. I like the first solution. (I don't thing the second works.)